# Mute audio when unplug headset

Tags: android

i'm trying to mute audio when unplug headset. I have a BroadcastReceiver and i do this:

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.hasExtra("state")){
         if (headsetConnected && intent.getIntExtra("state", 0) == 0){
             myActivity.music.setVolume((float) 0);
             headsetConnected = false;

         } else if (!headsetConnected && intent.getIntExtra("state", 0) == 1){
            headsetConnected = true;
             myActivity.music.setVolume((float) 1);
         }
     }
}
```

But when i unplug the headset the music still sound for a second.
How can i fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it.. It work for sure..

```
private class NoisyAudioStreamReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            pause();
        }
    }
}

private IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY);

private void startPlayback() {
    registerReceiver(myNoisyAudioStreamReceiver(), intentFilter);
}

private void stopPlayback() {
    unregisterReceiver(myNoisyAudioStreamReceiver);
}
```

I found the answer at this link: http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-output.html

Don't forget to add this permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG"></uses-permission>
```